# Is there a maximum IOPS for MySQL asynchronous replication on the slave server?

Tags: mysql, replication, performance, innodb, optimization

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. I have a simple Master-Slave setup with MySQL 8.0.15 installed on both systems. In day-to-day operations the slave keeps up the Master with no issue, but unfortunately with our network, the connection between the two server will sometimes be down for a couple hours or more. When this happens and the connection finally comes back up, it appears the relay logs are written on the slave at the expected speed (network speed), but the application of these logs into the MySQL database is not reaching the full potential of the physical disks.

The RAM and CPU allotted are not anywhere near capped either. When replication is catching up on the slave, the disks only reach around 600KB/s, but in typical operations (Windows operations) these SSDs can reach > 500MB/s. I know these are more 'random' writes, but I was not expecting this much of a performance drop off. This is actually the same speed as a similar setup we have that use only spinning disks spec'ed at far less IOPS.

The hardware/software is the same on the master and slave: The data partition is setup in a separate RAID-10 of SSDs with the OS and application on a separate RAID 1, 64GB RAM, 88 'CPU's, both are running Windows 2016 with MySQL 8.0.15, and they are using similar configuration files. Here are the startup configs I am currently using:

[client]
port=3306
default-character-set=utf8
[mysql]
no-beep
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir="W:/Data"
character-set-server=utf8
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="S:/general.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="S:/slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-bin="S:/bin"
log-error="S:/error.log"
server-id=10
lower_case_table_names=1
secure-file-priv=""
loose-local-infile=1
max_connections=500
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=7G
thread_cache_size=48
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=12G
key_buffer_size=11M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_data_home_dir="W:/Data"
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_log_buffer_size=120M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G
innodb_log_file_size=15G
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=1000
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=1M
max_allowed_packet=1G
slave_max_allowed_packet=1G
max_connect_errors=2147483648
open_files_limit=4161
sort_buffer_size=2M
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
loose_mysqlx_port=33060

## REPLICATION

replicate-same-server-id=0
sync_binlog=1
gtid-mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=true

## Slave optimizations

slave-parallel-type=LOGICAL_CLOCK
slave-parallel-workers=88
slave-compressed-protocol=ON
log-slave-updates=0
binlog-group-commit-sync-delay=4000
binlog-group-commit-sync-no-delay-count=5
binlog-row-image=MINIMAL
binlog-format=STATEMENT

All of our databases use solely innodb tables. I have attempted various optimizations from my research online. I have tried adjusting slave-parallel settings and various innodb settings, none of which seem to have an affect on disk throughput when the slave is catching up. Does anyone see anything here I need to adjust or any recommendations on how to go about troubleshooting this? Or even if you think I should be looking at hardware vs. software? Thank you!

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
software for Windows at this URL  https://github.com/pmachapman
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Hey @WilsonHauck thanks for following up with my question. I will attempt to get than information for you. I was messing around with values this morning and restarted services, but next week it have have been up for >24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, have a GREAT weekend.

Comment: Will have time to analyze your system this LONG Thanksgiving weekend if you could post information requested Nov 22 at 3:08.

Comment: Hey @WilsonHauck thanks for following up again. This week has been a little crazy so sorry for not getting back to you. I'd have it faster, but it's on a closed system so I'll have to manually fill in a lot of those values instead of a copy/paste. I'll work on it today.

Comment: Your comment seems like you can not SSH login as root, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; copy/paste to a local text file. ditto for global variables, SFPL, etc.  If not, it will be very difficult for you to know which items are truly critical for performance tuning.  Do what you can.

Comment: @WilsonHauck No, unfortunately you are correct. I can access the server (through RDP not SSH), but cannot copy anything from that network externally. My plan was to just manually substitute these values for you after running the same statements on a local instance, but after looking through them this will be quite a bit of work ... I'll have to reevaluate and see if there's a way I can get this data exported from that network. Sorry about that, but thanks for taking an interest. I will get back to you!

Comment: @WilsonHauck In addition, after some further digging last Friday, I found that this slave server was only utilizing 9 of the 88 `parallel_slave_workers` I had assigned with >86% of writes being done on two of those threads. (This is when working off a backlog). I think this has to do with workload, but I may make a separate question addressing this finding.

Comment: Sounds like your SLAVE server needs to be tuned.  Same information would be required to analyze for suggestions.  When you have RDP to your server, logged in, can you from MySQL client prompt SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  see about 400+ results by scrolling down?  If so, you should be able to ctrl+home, copy to clipboard, switch to your local computer and start Notepad, paste, save to a local TEXT file.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the content author of the website mentioned in my profile, Network Profile with downloadable FREE Utility Scripts, tips and contact information.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry, I’m doing a terrible job explaining the network this server resides on. I’ll send you a Skype message after the holiday to explain further. Have a happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate fix for the Slave

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2;
```

This should speed up the slave a little.

Go to my.cnf on the Slave and add

```
[mysqld]
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

and restart mysqld.

Please read my old post [Dynamic change to innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29963/dynamic-change-to-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit/29974#29974) for more clarification.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've been using various answers of yours already as I start my dba career. I've set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2 and it does increase disk write speed from about 600KB/s to 1.7MB/s. I know this leaves the slave open to 1 second of data loss, which I suppose is fine as a permanent option for a slave. Since I am on Windows, my two options for innodb_flush_method are unbuffered or normal and I have stuck with the default of unbuffered.

Comment: If I were to ask this same question with a Master-Master setup, I would be hesitant making the same change because of being non-ACID compliant. In this case, are there any other recommendations you may have for configuration to speed this up? I'm concerned replication may not keep up for the same reasons if we increase the amount of data being inserted into the database.

Comment: Perhaps with Master/Master, you should limit all INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs to one Master. That active master should have ACID compliance. The passive Master can relax its ACID and only serve SELECT queries.